# Nodeunit test hangs for async db call ORMnomnom

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, node.js, nodeunit

I am trying to write unit test for async db calls. I'm using *NodeJS* with *ORMnomnom* package installed as orm db access and *nodeunit* for unit testing.
But it hang for this simple test:

Here is code test\test1.js

```
modelsdb = require('../model/model_db')

exports['test db'] = function (test) {
  test.expect(1);
  console.log('test db');
  modelsdb.MyTable.objects.all( function (err, data) { 
    test.ok(true, "this assertion should pass"); 
    test.done();
    console.log('test must finish here!');
  });
}

exports.testSomething = function(test){
  console.log('testSomething');
  test.expect(1);
  test.ok(true, "this assertion should pass");
  test.done();
};
```

When I run this test all assertions passed, I see my messages in console: 'test db' 'test must finish here!' 'testSomething' (means that test.done() reached inside callback function) but test doesn't finish. I need to stop it manually, get: 'Process finished with exit code 1'. If I change to test.ok(false,""), so I get AssertionError but test doesn't finish either. If I remove 'test db' and left only testSomething function - test finished as expected, all assertion passed.

I also try *testpilot* package which is based on *nodeunit*. 
It gives

```
test1
   FAIL : test db
      an error occurred during test:
         Error: timed out waiting for test
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Rename "test db" to something without a space character and it should work

Comment: @jibsales, I tried without spaces, the same, after all tests passed still in hang state.

Comment: Try replacing your async DB call with setTimeout() to make sure the ORM isn't hanging on a connection or something else in the background that would keep the process from exiting properly.

Answer (score 2):

Add a [`tearDown`](https://github.com/caolan/nodeunit#groups-setup-and-teardown) method to your exports to close mongoose's connection pool.  As long as it's still open the test won't exit.

You don't show how you're opening your mongoose connection, but something like this:

```
exports.tearDown = function (callback) {
    mongoose.disconnect(callback);
};
```

Comment: Better: `mongoose.disconnect(callback);`

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue with nodeunit and q/mongoose - There is a [bug](https://github.com/caolan/nodeunit/pull/162) that has been opened for it.  I've tried to do the terrible `process.exit(0)` after calling `test.done()`, but any logging that is pending may not be flushed, so it isn't ideal.  Ended up having to call `process.exit(0)` in a timeout block.